# How to view image on button click?

Tags: jquery

How can I view image file by click on near button? here input type file is dynamically creating.

View,

```js
$(document).on("click", "#idImgView", function() {
  var idProjectTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("idProjectTitle");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectidAppe" class="form-group">
  <label>Project Photos</label>
  <div class="form-group file-uploader">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
      <input type="text" id="txtProjectTitle-0" style="height: 35px !important" class="form-control input-lg" disabled="" placeholder="download.jpg">
      <div id="clearbtn-0" class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="browse btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">
          Browse
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="idProjectTitle file" name="fileUploadphoto-0">
        </div>
        <div id="idImgDelete" class="browse btn btn-primary">Delete</div>
        <div id="idImgView" class="browse btn btn-primary">View</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group file-uploader">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
      <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
      <input type="text" id="txtProjectTitle-1" style="height: 35px !important" class="form-control input-lg" disabled="" placeholder="Lotus_flower.jpg~c200.jpg">
      <div id="clearbtn-1" class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="browse btn btn-primary" style="display: none;"> Browse<input type="file" accept="image/*" class="idProjectTitle file" multiple="multiple" name="fileUploadphoto-1"></div>
        <div id="idImgDelete" class="browse btn btn-primary">Delete</div>
        <div id="idImgView" class="browse btn btn-primary">View</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible by using `document.getElementsByClassName`? How can do this?

Comment: __Identifiers must be unique__, Your HTML is invalid

Comment: here fileUpload is dynamically creating one, like a list of fileupload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM traversal methods to target the desired element. Use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to common parent then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the element.

Note **Identifiers must be unique**, Here is the snippet. Here in the snippet [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) is used to get the reference of DOM element.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".idImgView", function() {
  var sourceElement = $(this).closest(".file-uploader").find('.idProjectTitle').get(0);
  var target = $(this).closest(".file-uploader").find('.imagedisplay').get(0);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    target.src = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(sourceElement.files[0]);
  console.log(sourceElement.files)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectidAppe" class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group file-uploader">
    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
      <div id="clearbtn-0" class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="browse btn btn-primary">
          Browse
          <input multiple type="file" accept="image/*" class="idProjectTitle file" name="fileUploadphoto-0">
        </div>
        <button class="browse btn btn-primary idImgView">View</button>
        <img class="imagedisplay" src="" width="100"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you could just use the following selector to get all the elements with `idProjectTitle` class  :

```
var idProjectTitle = $('.idProjectTitle');
```

**NOTE :** `id` should be unique in the same document so try to replace `idImgDelete` by common class or incremented identifiers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, now getting all fileupload details, from there How can I identify respective view button clicked image path and then show image: now... value:"C:\fakepath\download.jpg"